# Is there a way to measure the compliance of a topology image?

Tags: python, matlab, optimization, topology

I have thousands of topology structures/2D images like this one:

[image]

and I need to measure the structural compliance of each. Is there a way to do this on Matlab or Python?

Comment: How is the compliance of an image defined?

Comment: If it can be calculated, there is a way in both Matlab and Python.